# What is the different between parent, super and base class in php?

Tags: php

I searched google but I can't understand What is the different between parent, super and base class in php ? Is it same ?

```
class parentClass{
    public $name = 'shibbir';
    public $age = '29';

    public function show(){
        return $this->name . $this->age;
    }
}


class childClass extends parentClass{
    public function showParentClass(){
        return parent::show();

    }
}

$object =  new childClass();
echo $object->showParentClass();
```

so is this `parentClass` is called parent / supper / base class ? and I am extending `parentClass` to `childClass`. is it called `inheritance` ?

Comment: I would say all those terms refer to the same concept.

Answer (score 1):

Yes what you're showing in the example is called inheritance, with a child class extending parent class.

Check out here
http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.inheritance.php

Super / base class would be properly just an alternative name depending on your choice of programming language. They're referring to the same thing in PHP.